# App keeps getting rejected for user_friends - Facebook

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-friends

Basically Facebook keeps rejecting our app for our request to utilise user_friends but won't give us any reasoning as to why, which is super helpful.

I'm not the most technically gifted in the world so please speak slowly and point! The info I have is below. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

I’m using my admin account and when I try to login with ‘user_friends’ permissions error appears.

Here is my code:

```
guard let viewController = view as? UIViewController else { return }
  let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
  fbLoginManager.logOut()
  fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.native
  view?.setupStatusBar(style: .default)
  fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: [“user_friends”], from: 
viewController) { (result, error) in

  }
```

[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsyjf.png)

Comment: what happens when you print the error?

Comment: Are you actually talking about app review here, or just about trying to test this permission with your app admin account before you submit for review? Is your app still in dev mode?

Comment: No submission of actual app - everything else we needed passed first time, just this that keeps getting us stuck

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error **because** your app isn't approved yet.

There is a really bad UX regarding the new Facebook app review, but you'll find informations regarding your review in **your inbox on the developer app page**. You will probably have to do the business verification if you haven't already.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but all business verification done but they are requesting a screen cast so I think the solution is to build it in to the test build and send that. Thanks all

Comment: @user10233083 Yes, you have to send them a screen cast to show the use of user_friends permission. I guess you have found this information in the Inbox as I suggested ?